# Disable video that is autoplaying at lower widths for mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want my HTML5 video to disappear at 600px, as mobile phones don't autoplay and can't seem to run the javascript very well etc. The issue is my @media query to display none at 600px only non-displays the visual part of the video, not the audio - But I need the audio disabled as well below 600px. I have been researching this already on stack overflow and there are some possible solutions already, but I need help relating the code to my program if possible please.

There is a complication as I already have javascript running on my 'video' and "videoEnd" tags which is working fine and makes the video, padding and text disappear once the video is auto played.

Here is my existing code:

```
<html>
  <video id="video" width="" height="" controls autoplay > 
    <source src="clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.  
  </video>
  <div id="videoEnd" style="display:block">James Presents</div> 
</html>

<script>

    document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) { e = window.event; }

        // What you want to do after the event
        document.getElementById('video').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('videoEnd').style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

A previous answer is suggesting use this code to disable the video completely at a certain width, but being a novice I am not sure if the code is jquery or javascript and how to relate the code below to my id tags?

```
$(function() {

  // onload
  if(document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
    $('video').attr('autoplay', true);
  }

  // If you want to autoplay when the window is resized wider than 780px 
  // after load, you can add this:

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if(document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
        $('video').attr('autoplay', true);
    }
  });
});
```

UPDATED CODE BELOW

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (document.body.clientWidth >= 630) {
video.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
video.classList.remove('hide');
}

$(window).resize(function() {
if (document.body.clientWidth >= 630) {
video.classList.remove('hide')
video.play();
video.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
} else {
video.classList.add('hide');
video.removeAttribute('autoplay');
video.pause();
}
});
});
</script>

<video id="video" width="" height="" controls class="hide" >
<source src="clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>

<div id="videoEnd" style="display:block">James Presents</div>

<script>





          document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) { e = window.event; }

        // What you want to do after the event
        document.getElementById('video').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('videoEnd').style.display="none";
    }
</script>

//ALL CSS THAT RELATES IS BELOW
.hide {
display: none;
}

#videoEnd
{

margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
top: 15%;
left: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 

font-size:325%;
color:white;
font-family: Kroftsmann;
src:url('Kroftsmann.ttf');
}



video {
margin-top:10%;
width:65%;
position: fixed;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
background-color:rgb(15, 15, 15);
padding:2000px;
z-index:9999;



}


@media screen and (max-width:630px){
#videoEnd
{
visibility:hidden;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:630px){
video
{
display: none;
visibility:hidden;
}    

}
```

Comment: It's jquery. It seems work.

Comment: Ok thanks blackmiaool, so is the code already acting on the html5 video tag and no further adjustment in the jquery code needed?

Comment: Seems right. Better try it first. It's jquery, so u should load jquery lib first.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `autoplay` from your HTML video element to disable that as the default action, add the class `.hide` (or whatever you use to hide the element) so it's hidden by default. Then on load, add `autoplay` and remove `.hide` if the viewport width > your breakpoint.

Then on resize, if the viewport is < your breakpoint, add a CSS element that will hide the video (`display: none;`), remove the `autoplay` attribute if it exists, and `pause()` the video. If the viewport is > your breakpoint, undo all of that.

```js
$(function() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  if (document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
    video.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
    video.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (document.body.clientWidth >= 870) {
      video.classList.remove('hide')
      video.play();
      video.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
    } else {
      video.classList.add('hide');
      video.removeAttribute('autoplay');
      video.pause();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>something before the video</p>
<video id="video" controls class="hide">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<p>something after the video</p>
```

Comment: Michael Coker thanks very much. I followed your instructions and soon got the program correctly disabling video audio also, so all good.

Comment: Michael Coker and all - The only slight bug is whenever I resize the window after the clip has played, just the audio part (not the visual) part of the video is re- triggered. Anyone got an idea how to remove the bug?

Comment: @watchglass49 sorry, I don't understand. Does that happen with my demo? If so can you describe it a different way? "whenever I resize the window after the clip has played" So you play it all the way through, it stops, you resize the window (and keep the width > 870), the audio starts but the video doesn't? If so, I'm not seeing that with my demo.

Comment: Sure, the function works fine, enabling and disabling the video depending on what width your browser is. Once the video has played, in my code the video, and it's surrounding padding and a text element are programmed to disappear. But when all has disappeared and I resize the browser window, just the audio part of the video (not visual part) replays - this could be to do with the other javascript parts of my program, I'm sure your part works fine Michael.

Comment: @watchglass49 Oh so the video disappears and doesn't re-appear - only the audio starts playing? I thought you were saying the video re-appears, it just doesn't play, but the audio plays - if that's happening, that's weird. But if the video just isn't "un-hiding", then that means your JS that un-hides the video isn't firing. Feel free to share your code and I'll have a look.

Comment: Ok thanks, I pasted in all the code that relates to this above :)

Comment: @watchglass49 There is no point in having your video respond to a window resize since users opens a page and look at it, not resizing to see what happens, hence the simple code I provided in my answer is more than enough than messing around with resize handler ... which by the way slow down your page even more

Comment: @watchglass49 change these 2 lines `document.getElementById('video').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('videoEnd').style.display="none";`  to `document.getElementById('video').classList.add('hide');
        document.getElementById('videoEnd').classList.add('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

The code suggestion is a mix of jQuery and plain javascript.

Here is one way, using plain javascript, that will, on page load, check if width is wider than 600, and if so, show and play the video. Your existing event handler will hide it when done.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 600) {
    var vid = document.getElementById('video');
    var wrap = document.getElementById('videowrapper');
    wrap.classList.toggle('hide');
    vid.play();
    vid.addEventListener('ended',function(e) {
      wrap.classList.toggle('hide');    
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="videowrapper" class="hide">
  <video id="video" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  <div>James Presents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: LGSon - Thanks for your answer, I got it working already with the other - but I'm going to study your answer also to help improve my coding.

Comment: @watchglass49 Updated it to contain also the text at the bottom

Comment: LGSon I tried your code and got it working reliably so much appreciated. (I just changed '200' in the code to the '600' width I wanted.

Comment: @watchglass49 Thanks, and good you got it working ... also updated my answer to 600 (the 200 I used for testing and forgot to change it back)